# vis.js Network (react-vis-network) why beforeDrawing fires muliply times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js

I'm using vis.js Network (@lifeomic/react-vis-network) and React to build some graph. I want to use beforeDrawing event to get acsess to canvas so I could do additional drawning. The question is why beforeDrawing fires so many times? For instance my graph look like this:
[image: graph]
I've added debug log:

```
    rawNetwork.on("beforeDrawing", (ctx) => {
        console.log("Debug log: \n", "beforeDrawing");
    }
```

And console output is:
[image: debug log]

I want to draw my custom models only ones, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If someone struggling with this like me, try to read documentation more carefully. There is a method called "Once".

from vis docs:

> Set an event listener only once. After it has taken place, the event listener will be removed. Depending on the type of event you get different parameters for the callback function. Look at the event section of the documentation for more information.